# Where can I set my ssl certificates in mean.io?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, mean.io

I want to server my mean.io application only in https, but I cannot find where I can do. That is very weird, because mean.io has a built in login mechanism, it should be https by default, or it should be easy and documented how to do it.

I asked it here, but no response: https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/745

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `/config/env/all.js`, around line 55, modify here:

```
// Paths to key and cert as string
ssl: {
  key: '',
  cert: ''
  }
},
```

Comment: Can you elaborate and show what needs to be changed and explain how? Otherwise this is basically a link-only answer, and therefor invalid.